# The Common Thread

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What common property unites all of the following numbers?

> 4, 9, 60, 101, 400, 450, 910, 1010

The set of numbers that share this common property is not limited to just these eight, but the list should provide enough information to solve it.

Comment: Can we also assume that no other numbers below 1010 share this commonality?

Comment: @breadbox I didn't find any more below 1010 but there could have been some that I missed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are the numbers whose roman numeral translations are in strict alphabetical order (so no repetitions).
>
>   `4=IV, 9=IX, 60=LX, 101=CI, 400=CD, 450=CDL, 910=CMX, 1010=MX`

Comment: If this is correct, then there's also 104, 109, 401, 404, 409, 501, 504, 509, 550, 905, and 1005.

Comment: You're right, those ones fit too. I wasn't sure if putting a lot of numbers would give it away too quickly so I stopped once I had found 8 :)

Comment: If you take out 450 and 910 from the original list, you get a tighter pattern that also includes 501, 505, 550, 900, 1005, ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is

> Roman numerals with 1 letter, in alphabetical order; then those with 2 letters,  etc.

and the source is http://oeis.org/A003588